# SQL Server CE 4.0 Local Cache Agent?! EF Support?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-4.1, sql-server-ce, microsoft-sync-framework

Is there a possibility in the near future provide a SQL Server Compact 4.0 DB to synchronize with SQL Server, unfortunately, offers some of the SyncFramework for this version at no SyncCeProvider .... and the opportunity to work with a local cache async one is also forbidden, because it is supported only in version 3.5.

Unfortunately, I am clueless and if needed an alternative offered by the DB once support for the Entity Framework and the Local Cache Agent.

The version of SQL Server Compact 3.5 would work but unfortunately I have the problem that the auto-increment columns are not generated ..... too bad someone has an alternative suggestion?

Comment: In my limited work with SyncFx, I would say auto-increment/identity columns as primary keys are a terrible idea. I've had no problem with them in a one-way master->slave approach but they fall extremely short when you're trying to sync data from x slaves to a single table on the master.

Answer (score 0):

The SqlCeSyncProvider can actually work with SQL CE 4.0 although unsupported.

how about SQL Express? or SQL Express 2012 LocalDB instead of SQL CE?